# Using mapbox, how can I add a borders layer over the top of the satellite image layer?

Tags: gis, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Essentially I would like to reproduce the open gl example map - https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/satellite-map/ but be able to use the mapbox.js API to add customer markers and clustering.

The streets map has the information, but I don't know how to get just the border line and country/state name layers added onto a satellite map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to edit the mapbox-gl style file they are referencing: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-styles/styles/satellite-v7.json.

All the available layer styles are listed under `"layers":[...]`, e.g.

```
{
  ...
  "layers": [{
    "id": "background",
    "type": "background",
    "paint.labels": {
      "background-color": "rgb(4,7,14)"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "satellite",
    "type": "raster",
    "source": "satellite",
    ...
  }]
}
```

So, if you're looking to keep only borders and country and state labels, find the objects with ids that represent these layers, likely `"province_border"`, `"country_border"`, `"country_label"`, and `"state_label"`, and delete *every other* layer object.